# I'm not getting a welcome email after registration

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel. I am using the `mailtrap.io` driver for testing to send a welcome email after the user has registered but I am not getting the welcome email.

I am only getting an email for password reset. Very weird because I did this before and I'm not understanding.

Can someone please help me? here is my code:

> SomeController.php

```php
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        Mail::send('layouts.welcomeemail', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
            $message->to($data['email']);
        });
    }

// The rest of my code.
```

Comment: Issue is with you are returning the User before email sends, assign it to a variable and return after Mail statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I solved it!!!

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\DemoMail;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'profile/create';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user= User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

             ]);

       $email = $data['email'];
        Mail::to($email)->send(new DemoMail());

                            return $user;




    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for taking time out in helping me with this. If anyone is searching for the answer here it is

Answer (score 0):

the problem is as soon as you create the user you return the returned User Object and the code for `mail` never actually executes
You gotta do it like;

```php
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        Mail::send('layouts.welcomeemail', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
            $message->to($data['email']);
        });

        return $user;

    }
```

Comment: I just did I had to click it twice

Comment: @Stephany.S123 see my second answer

Answer (score 0):

There are still problems with your mail code as you are not using the `$data` variable in the function as i wrote below

```
Mail::send('layouts.welcomeemail', $data, 
      function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
            $message->to($data['email'] , $data['name']);
        });
```

Or there is one more opion just to clear your code , when a user is registered the laravel fires a `registered` method just override the method as written below, i dont have any idea if old versions of laravel support `registered` method or not but laravel 5.5 does

```
 protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{

   Mail::send('layouts.welcomeemail', $user , 
    function($message) use($user)
        {
            $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');

        });
}
```

Comment: im using 5.6.7 I'll try this one and I will get back at you as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: Look the `registered` method is only gonna work if you are using the laravel default register controller

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I trued everything I even tried your last answer again and its not sending.